# Heroku ruby error after pg:pull

Tags: ruby, heroku, pg

I used heroku quite without any problems for months.

Today I tried to make a local database to separate the server side one from development. I followed the tutorial, installed PG, then used the heroku pg:pull command. It seemed to do something (and it did: created a new database locally, but without the schema and tables -- maybe because I use a named schema, not the default one?).

After the pg:pull it terminated, I was not able to start any heroku commands anymore. I get:

```
> heroku local web -f Procfile.windows <nul
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ffi (LoadError)
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows/root_certs.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `require_relative'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/windows.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/vendor/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/rest_client.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/auth.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/analytics.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-2.1.7/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:27:in `<main>'
```

I tried to reinstall heroku toolbelt, but with no result.

I am using Windows.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: have you tried installing `ffi`? That's what the error suggests

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all the suggestions and answered!

It turned to be a simple broken release from Heroku Toolbelt. They rolled it back and I reinstalled Heroku. It solved the problem.